# Swagger / Open API 3 - optional fields(/properties) in a JSON response object

Tags: yaml, swagger, openapi

Im documenting my endpoint with Open Api 3.0.2 and generate a swagger ui interface from the yaml.
My service takes a soap response and generates a json response. The elements on the soap response however are optional.

The json is generated based on the present elements in the soap response. Is there a way to mark some of the values as optional? I was thinking about the anyOf property but it doesnt work on the components level of the yaml (at least, I coudn't get it to work).
Take below example, say the json response can have all these properties but it could only have a few of them. Can I make this clearer in my yaml?

```
openapi: 3.0.0
...
paths:
  /path:
    get:
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Success
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Product'

components:
  schemas:
    Product:
      type: object
      properties:
        productid:
          type: string
        origin:
          type: string
        shortname:
          type: string
        names:
          type: array
          items:
            type: string
        price:
          type: string
        shipping:
          type: string
```

Comment: See the ^^ linked question. All properties are optional by default, unless you put them into the `required` list.

Comment: Ah I see, I missed that question. Thanks!